# Passing multiple search arguments to Alfresco slingshot search Webscript

Tags: search, lucene, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I'm using the below search Webscript in Alfresco one 5.1.

> http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/slingshot/node/search?q=@name:somename&store=workspace://SpacesStore&lang=lucene

It works fine with free text search & single named parameter.

1) Now how to incorporate more than one search parameter in the search query & include other custom fields (I've set the property's Index to - List of values - whole match to make it searchable)

2) How to specify to search only with in a particular folder in path ? 
  If I specify the path in workspace://SpacesStore/MyPath I get an error message

> Exception: 10010085 No solr query support for store workspace:

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Lucene language ([short tutorial](http://alfrescoblog.com/2014/07/09/alfresco-lucene-tutorial/))

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/slingshot/node/search
   ?lang=lucene
   &store=workspace://SpacesStore
   &q=
     TYPE:"cm:folder" 
     AND PATH:"/app:company_home//*" 
     AND @cm\:name:"SOMETHING"
```

### CMIS language

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/slingshot/node/search
   ?lang=cmis-alfresco
   &store=workspace://SpacesStore
   &q=
      SELECT * 
      FROM cmis:folder 
      WHERE 
        name:somename LIKE 'SOMETHING' 
        AND IN_FOLDER('workspace://SpacesStore/gfgdrdgdfg-rfew-sdfsdf-sfsdf-ssfsdfd')
```

or CMIS endpoint:

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser/
   ?cmisselector=query
   &maxItems=10
   &skipCount=0
   &succinct=true
   &q=
      SELECT * 
      FROM cmis:folder 
      WHERE 
        name:somename LIKE 'SOMETHING' 
        AND IN_FOLDER('workspace://SpacesStore/gfgdrdgdfg-rfew-sdfsdf-sfsdf-ssfsdfd')
```

[Test it](http://localhost:8080/share/page/console/admin-console/node-browser#state=panel%3Dsearch%26search%3DSELECT%2520*%2520%250AFROM%2520cmis%253Afolder%2520%250AWHERE%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520name%253Asomename%2520LIKE%2520'SOMETHING'%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520AND%2520IN_FOLDER('workspace%253A%252F%252FSpacesStore%252Fgfgdrdgdfg-rfew-sdfsdf-sfsdf-ssfsdfd')%26lang%3Dcmis-alfresco%26store%3Dworkspace%253A%252F%252FSpacesStore), more info: https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-5898-cmis-query-language

### New Alfresco 5.2 Search REST API

> The default search language is **afts** ([Alfresco Full Text Search](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/rm-searchsyntax-intro.html)),
>   but you can also specify **cmis**, and **lucene**.

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Basic *****' -d 
'{
    "query": {
       "language": "lucene",
       "query": "TYPE:\"cm:folder\" AND PATH:\"/app:company_home//*\" AND @cm\\:name:\"SOMETHING\""
    },
    "paging": {
      "maxItems": 5,
      "skipCount": 0
    }
}' 
'http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/search/versions/1/search'
```

Comment: Brilliant ! Thanks a ton @imagine. Works flawlessly :)