# Search for files in Alfresco based on the content model properties using Rest API

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm trying to implement searching of files in **Alfresco** based on the **properties of the content model** of the document.

**I found this ReST API:**

GET /alfresco/s/slingshot/search?term={term?}&tag={tag?}&site={site?}&container={container?}&sort={sort?}&query={query?}&repo={repo?}

But I'm not sure how to pass the property name of the document in the query parameter.

**For ex:**

My docuemt content model is: dc:InvoiceModel

Property name is: dc:doctype.

So, I want to pass the **dc:doctype** as query parameter as **Sales Invoice** for example to fetch **all** the documents of the type Sales Invoice. The documents are inside a folder in the documentLibrary

**I tried doing this:**

http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s/slingshot/search?container=documentLibrary/newfolder&sort=dc:dc:doc...false&repo=true&startIndex=0&query={"dc:doctype":"Sales Invoice","datatype":"d:text"}

But I'm getting zero records found. Could you please help me do this.

**Alfresco Version:**

**Alfresco Share v5.1.f**
(r125711-b6, Aikau 1.0.63, Spring Surf 5.1.f, Spring WebScripts 6.5, Freemarker 2.3.20-alfresco-patched, Rhino 1.7R4-alfresco-patched, Yui 2.9.0-alfresco-20141223)

**Alfresco Community v5.1.0**
(r127059-b7) schema 10001

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

be careful: slingshot is not a public API (but in 5.1 you don't have a public search API). In 5.2 you should use the [Alfresco Content Services REST API](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/?urls.primaryName=Search%20API)

In this SO question you should already find you answer: [Passing multiple search arguments to Alfresco slingshot search Webscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358988/passing-multiple-search-arguments-to-alfresco-slingshot-search-webscript)

some remarks:

- container: could be one of the site container types like `documentLibrary` but only makes sense together with a site
- query: (defaults to [Alfresco FTS](https://docs.alfresco.com/search-services/latest/using/)) should look like `dc\:doctype:"Sales Invoice"` but should be url encoded. You could also add a PATH query as shown in the answer above